# How do I list the automated backups in RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is there a way I can use the `rds-describe-db-snapshots` command to find the most recent automated backup?

It used to be possible with the -t option but Amazon has since removed that capability and now it only lists manual backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As at 10th May 2014, it looks like you can still use the --t flag to list only automated backups.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/CommandLineReference/CLIReference-cmd-DescribeDBSnapshots.html

From there, you should be able to parse the output to determine your latest snapshots.

```
rds-describe-db-snapshots --t automated

DBSNAPSHOT  rds:<NAME>-2014-05-06-17-12  2014-05-06T17:12:39.779Z  <NAME>  2014-04-12T15:50:57.035Z  mysql  300  3000  available  100  username  default:mysql-5-6  5.6.13  general-public-license  automated  <VPC>
DBSNAPSHOT  rds:<NAME>-2014-05-07-17-11  2014-05-07T17:11:48Z      <NAME>  2014-04-12T15:50:57.035Z  mysql  300  3000  available  100  username  default:mysql-5-6  5.6.13  general-public-license  automated  <VPC>
```